# Passing a variable to the form action

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So I have first form in which user chooses profile:

```
class ProfileChoice(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None)
        super(ProfileChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['login'].queryset = Profile.objects.all().filter(created_by_id = self.user_id)

    login = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= None, label='Profile')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('login',)
```

On submit I need to redirect him to the next form which is this:

```
class TranslatorChoice(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None)
        super(TranslatorChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['owner'].queryset = Translator.objects.all().filter(owner_id = self.user_id)
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset =  None)
    class Meta:
        model = Translator
        fields = ('owner',)
```

with this view:

```
class ProfileOwner(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/update.html'
    success_url="/account/"
    form_class = TranslatorChoice
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(client_check, login_url='/account/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProfileOwner, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user_id'] = self.request.user.id
        return kwargs
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        profile = super(ProfileOwner, self).get_object(queryset)
        if profile.created_by != self.request.user:
            raise Http404("Profile doesn't exist")
        return profile
```

The update needs to be performed on the profile which was chosen in the first form. I am trying to do it with passing a `pk` to the URL. Here's `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)', ProfileOwner.as_view(), name='profile_owner_update')
```

and my template is here:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Add profile</h2>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'profile_owner_update' pk=id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Choose</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and the view that is supposed to pass the `id` variable to the form action is here:

```
def link_translator(request):
    id = 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileChoice(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():
            login = form.cleaned_data['login']
            id = Profile.objects.get(login=login)
            id = id.id
            return render(request, 'registration/linkt.html', {'form': form,
            'id': id})
    else:
        form = ProfileChoice(user_id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'registration/linkt.html', {'form': form,
    'id': id})
```

It obviously doesn't work and the `id = 1` in the beginning is like a test default value for the form to actually render on GET request.

Answer (score 0):

In `link_translator` view, instead of `render` on POST, you need to do redirect to the view with second form:

```
def link_translator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileChoice(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():
            login = form.cleaned_data['login']
            profile = Profile.objects.get(login=login)
            second_url = django.urls.reverse('profile_owner_update', args=[profile.id])
            return django.shortcuts.redirect(second_url)
    else:
        form = ProfileChoice(user_id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'registration/linkt.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: If I change my view to this then it just doesn't work because variable pk in my form action gets no value so the form just declines to render. Should I change something in my template to make it work?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you paste error/traceback here?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /linkt/
Reverse for 'profile_owner_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P<pk>\\d+)']

Comment: There was typo in original answer which I fixed. That line should be -

Comment: django.urls.reverse('profile_owner_update', args=[profile.id])

Comment: I figured that myself, this was causing syntax error and not this. Look at my template and form action. If I set form action to action="" then the form just won't submit and tell me to select a valid choice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223588/discussion-between-rawkymonk-and-eugene-prikazchikov).